# Event trigger for after dom object created javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript

If I dynamically create an element through the click of a button, for example, a video element, is there some way for me to attach some event listener that is fired right after the DOM object is created in jquery and javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hacky solution that assumes the first handler doesn't `.stopImmediatePropagation()`:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("video").on("something", function() {});
});
```

The idea is that the other button click handler created the elements, and then your handler fires after which attaches your handlers on the created video element. Modify selectors and code.

It's still less hacky than polling the dom for changes though.

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure but maybe use a call backfunction http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp